# Unexpected returned value of a user defined function

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream.h>

int someFunction(int &x, int c) {
    c=c-1;
    if(c==0) {
        return 1;
    }
    x=x+1;
    return someFunction(x,c) * x;
}

void main() {
    int p = 5;
    cout << someFunction(p,p);
}
```

This code return 6561 but I have no idea why. Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Did you run the code through a debugger?

Comment: 1) `<iostream>`. 2) `int main()`. 3) `std::cout`. All of those are necessary changes to make your code into standard C++.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have 5 iterations here:

```
1st iteration - C is 5 and reduced by 1 -> c=4 which is not 0 so we go on to "(++x) * someFunc".
2nd iteration - C is 4 and reduced by 1 -> c=3 which is not 0 so we go on to "(++x) * someFunc".
3rd iteration - C is 3 and reduced by 1 -> c=2 which is not 0 so we go on to "(++x) * someFunc".
4th iteration - C is 2 and reduced by 1 -> c=1 which is not 0 so we go on to "(++x) * someFunc".
5th iteration - C is 1 and reduced by 1 -> c=0 so we return 1.
```

At this point we have x * x * x * x * 1 and after the 4 increments x = 9 and so the value is 9 * 9 * 9 * 9 * 1 = 6561

This happens because the function is evaluated before the actual multiplication can take place but as the stack unwinds, at the moment of each multiplication, `x` which is passed by reference is already at it's last value, which is 9.

Comment: I'm fairly sure `x` can be evaluated to be 6, 7, or 8 before the function call takes place and changes it (as the order of evaluation is unspecified). Indeed doing `x * someFunction(x, c)` gives a [different result](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/aec2aff7c7da47ff).

Comment: @chris This is a bit compiler dependent, I suppose, But a reasonable compiler would have the address dereferencing done after the recursive call to `someFunc` and therefore set the updated value into the register used for multiplication.
Of course different optimizations might generate different results. Still this behavior would explain the value received in the question